# How to store Numeric.Sequence routine return value in context variable

Tags: talend

I am developing a Talend ETL job as follows.

I have source database from where I am extracting data in daily basis.My target table contains two columns id,name. For id column I am generating value from Numeric.Sequence("s1",1,1) routine. But my problem is when I am executing job it is generating value from start value i.e provided in Numeric.Sequence routine. But I want to get last generated value as a start value.

Solution : I can achieve it by extracting max id from table But i don't want to use table. 
I want to store max id value generated with Numeric.Sequence routine in context variable and use it as a start value when I will execute my job. I tried but it is generating with fresh value only.

Please let me know all the available options in Talend.

Comment: Talend is an object oriented tool. The sequence starting value for next job run cannot be set in this run. If you create an object in globalMap and store the next job's sequence start value, then during next job run that globalMap will be reinitialized. What you can do is, you can save the starting value for next job run, into a text file and read that file in the next job run.

Answer (score 0):

Job context is reset every time you execute the job. 
Keep in mind that you are running a Java program, variables are kept only when program is alive and not after.

A solution is to use a database sequence (example with postgreSQL) :

- add a sequence on id column of yout target table
- use "nextval(''::regclass)" in your output component (see image below)

[nextval_example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4n3VY.jpg)